# How to open inbuilt filemanager through code

Tags: android

I have an inbuilt filemanager in my phone. How can I call that through code in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own file manager as shown below. May be useful to you all.

Try this and correct me if I am wrong

```
public class FileManager extends Activity {

private String[] basePath = {Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "", "/mnt/sdcard2"};

private ListView listView;

private ArrayList<String> pathList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> fileList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_manager);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    pathList = new ArrayList<String>();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
    loadBasedata();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // Path is hardcoded
            if(pathList.size() == 0)
                pathList.add(basePath[0]);
            else
                pathList.add(pathList.get(pathList.size() - 1) + "/" + fileList.get(position));
            fileList.clear();
            // Add new files to list
            addFilesToList(pathList.get(pathList.size() - 1));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }); 
}
private void loadBasedata() {
    fileList.clear();

    fileList.add("Internal sdcard");
    File file = new File(basePath[1]);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        fileList.add("External sdcard");
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}   
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(pathList.isEmpty())
        finish();
    else if(pathList.size() == 1)
    {
        pathList.clear();
        loadBasedata();
    }
    else
    {
        fileList.clear();
        pathList.remove(pathList.size() - 1);
        addFilesToList(pathList.get(pathList.size() - 1));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
private void addFilesToList(String path) {
    File parentDir = new File(path);

    if(parentDir.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
        //this.adapter.add("Go Back");
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            String filename=files[i].getName();
            fileList.add(filename);        
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://"));

if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null)
    startActivity(intent);
```

Some android operating systems haven't got any file browser, so above validation is required.

Comment: that makes no changes in my app.

Intent fileMangerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, Uri.parse(Url));
startActivity(fileMangerIntent);

i tried this but it opens my root explorer not my filemanager.

Comment: What do you refer by "my filemanager" ? Is it your own file manager or downloaded one?