# File explorer Android

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to find a file explorer on Android but I find nothing.

I can only find tutorials to create one but this is not working out.

I'd like to find something like JFileChooser in java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create yourself I created one as shown below, I don't want to execute file I just got the name of the file choosen there, any doubt ask freely.

Mine is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423802/how-to-open-inbuilt-filemanager-through-code)