# opening sd-card section on click of button

Tags: android

Sorry, if i am repeating this question.

I am developing an simple file reading app. In that i am having multi line Edit text(Text Area) and a button.

I have file reading code.

But,On button click, I want to choose a file, from sdcard .

I dont want to hard code the path like "/sdcard/xyz.txt". User will simply click on button and then sdcard section will open, and user will choose his file.

So can anyone Please tell me how i can open sdcard section on click of button ?

Comment: So you want to open browser to access path from sdcard...

Comment: Not browser, i want to open sdcard section on click of button.

Comment: sdcard section means what??

Comment: In every 4.0.3 android device we have file browser in that we have local,sdcard and wireless manager sections. under sdcard section we can view all files stored on sdcard.This section i want to open on click of button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a open source project which gives you a complete file picker and can be invoked using intents

Use [this](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)

Like this :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://"));

if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null)
startActivity(intent);
```

I have created my own `filemanager`.
Try this link:[How to open inbuilt filemanager through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423802/how-to-open-inbuilt-filemanager-through-code)